# logstash configuration to execute a command to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, logstash, exec

i am running an ELK stack in 3 docker containers through host machine ubuntu 16.04
the problem is after configuring the logstash.conf file to execute a command like "ifconfig" or "netstat -ano"i get an error. my logstash.conf file is:

```html
input {
  exec {
  
    command => "netsat -ano"
    codec => "json"
    interval => 5
  }
}
output{
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]}
}
 i get this error after entering this command ( docker run -h logstash --name logstash --link elasticsearch:elasticsearch -it --rm -v "$PWD":/config-dir logstash -f /config-dir/logstash1.conf)
```

```
14:29:30.703 [[main]<exec] ERROR logstash.inputs.exec - Error while running command {:command=>"netsat -ano", :e=>#<IOError: Cannot run program "netsat" (in directory "/"): error=2, No such file or directory>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyIO.java:4380:in `popen'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-exec-3.1.2/lib/logstash/inputs/exec.rb:76:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-exec-3.1.2/lib/logstash/inputs/exec.rb:75:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-exec-3.1.2/lib/logstash/inputs/exec.rb:40:in `inner_run'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-exec-3.1.2/lib/logstash/inputs/exec.rb:34:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:443:in `inputworker'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:436:in `start_input'"]}
```

can anyone help please thanks in advance !

Comment: You typo'd `netstat` as `netsat`

Comment: actually it is netstat i knw it was a mistake i also tried "ifconfig" same error marked below

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide a full path for those commands, as the one Logstash runs with doesn't contain those directories.

```
input {
  exec {
    command => "/bin/netsat -ano"
    codec => "json"
    interval => 5
  }
```

}

Comment: actually it is "/sbin/netstat -ano" but it didn't work also same error marked below